# Loops and iterator C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

why iterator (int i) in my code equals n+1 at the end if loop means that it should stop at n?

```
int n, i, j;

cout << "N: ";
cin >> n;

int a[n];

for (int C = 0; C < n; C++){
    cout << "a[" << C+1 << "] = ";
    cin >> a[C];
   }

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (a[j] == i) {
            j = 500;
            break;
        }

    }
    cout << i << " ";
    if (j != 500) {
        break;
    }
}

cout << endl;
if (i == n+1){
    cout << 0 << " and i = " << i << endl;
}
```

here's the example of a compilation:

N: 5

a[1] = 1

a[2] = 2

a[3] = 3

a[4] = 4

a[5] = 5

1 2 3 4 5 
0 and i = 6

Program ended with exit code: 0

question is why i = 6?

Comment: `of a compilation` - I think this is output of execution.

Comment: Because it will continue until `i <= n` is false

Comment: for loop's format is `for( begin; end; inc/dec)` Your loop starts at one and after every iteration, it checks if `i<=n` even if `i=n` the condition is true and it will execute.

Answer (score 1):

A for-loop is semantically equivalent to (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)):

```
{
    init_statement
    while ( condition ) {
        statement
        iteration_expression ;
    } 
}
```

In your case that would be

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
    //...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{ 
    j = 0;
    while (j < n) {
        // ...
        j++;
    }
}
```

For the loop to stop, the condition (`j<n`) must become `false`. Hence if you check the counter after the loop you don't see the counter of the last iteraton but the value of the iteration that was not executed. Note that `j++` increments during the last iteration.

I would advice you to declare the loop counter only in the scope of the loop, to avoid confusion like the current one:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the reason is the typo in this code snippet

```
if (j != 500) {
    break;
}
```

that appears in the outer loop.

I think you mean

```
if (j == 500) {
    break;
}
```

Otherwise the outer loop continues to iterate because for each value of i there is a corresponding value in the array a according to the input.

Comment: I didnt understand that part of the code, but after reading this answer I have the feeling mine is not addressing the correct issue in OPs code. Anyhow, lets leave it for OP to decide

Answer (score 0):

because the test "i <= n" failed when i became 6. Therfore after the loop i == 6.

Answer (score 0):

The loop's condition reads "Do all this as long as i is lower or equal than n, and increment i after every round".

So the loop checks the condition, runs one time, then increments i. In the second to last round the condition will be true, the code will run and then `i` will be incremented. In the last round, the condition is no longer true and then the code is not executed nor is `i` incremented, but by now, it already is higher than you expect it to be